# Using .net 5.4 and a dependency that is not supported

Tags: asp.net-core, dnx, dnu

I am following the getting started ASP.NET 5 for Mac. (https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/getting-started-with-asp-net-5-and-visual-studio-code-on-a-mac.html). I noticed that they are using Twilio:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Twilio": "4.0.3"    
},
```

I am a bit confused because when I open this project in Visual Studio it complains that Twilio does not support framework v=5.4. Would it not be a bad idea to use this dependency since it doesn't support 5.4? Very confused here.

Edit for clearity:

They appear to clearly be targeting dnxcore50 in the frameworks section.
[image]

Comment: Looks like `Twilio` library currently is supported only on Mono platform when running on a Mac/Linux. It does not support running on CoreClr yet. Issue: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/issues/163

Comment: But i am targeting the dnxcore50 not Mono.

Comment: So as the link mentions, you cannot use `Twilio` on `dnxcore50` currently.

Comment: Well the tutorial is clearly targeting dnxcore50 and using Twilio. That is my confusion

Comment: Ok, so I now see your edited post...looks like the image is incorrect...i say this because the previous github issue itself talks about this very same tutorial page that you pointed :-)...also check about a user's comment about removing `dnxcore50` target and making it work :-)

Comment: So the tutorial that is centered around using Twilio with dnxcore50 is completely wrong great.

Comment: If you ask a new question how to send sms with twilio on dnxcore50/CoreClr I can answer that as I just implemented my own solution against their REST api